# Gauntlet of Kressh the Younger loophole?

Tags: star-wars

The Gauntlet is said to protect the wearer from all harm, however

1. What if the person wearing the gauntlet was exposed to a toxic gas or deadly pathogen?
2. What if the wearer was launched into space or into a star?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the sources that mentioned the artefact described either of those situations. The device sounds like a shield against damage by energy, not a life support device. Therefore, it can be guessed that it won't protect from vacuum or pathogens.

Answer (score -1):

Well I do not know if this info is in any way credible, but the official Wookieepedia site claims that "anything" that attempts to touch (reach) the wearer without his/her consent is blasted aside.

In theory anything the Wearer can actively perceive and pass judgment over whether he gives it consent to touch/reach him can be repelled no matter the Size.

Wookieepedia also Claims, that the Gauntlet could redirect Attacks into another direction without having to look that way. Whether or not this applies to the deflection in itself isn´t stated, but I thought it was worth noting.

So to conclude the theory: anything the wearer can perceive through his senses, be they biological or Force related, can be repelled.

What is not stated is whether or not the Gauntlet has a limit of what he can repel, since a sun is pretty Hot. Then again the Dark Jedi Hazzan survived a turbolaser barrage unscathed while wearing it in the *Star Wars - Knights of the Old Republic: Vindication* comics.

Force powers have been shown to work in a complete vacuum, best example being Plo Koon, when he defended his clone troopers from boarding droids in space. So it isn't a far stretch to say the Gauntlet's powers would do so as well, but the Gauntlet is not stated to have any life-support function.

Sorry for dragging this post out so long. In short the theory goes:

Deadly gas and pathogen - maybe

Sun - very big maybe

Vacuum - yes and no. Unless you can breathe in space, or have a life-support system the same rules apply to the wearer as to everyone else.

Final note: this is just a theory based on Wookieepedia articles. If there are any points I overlooked or got wrong, please feel free to tell me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do note however that answers based on evidence from official sources are much preferred to those based on unofficial sources, like Wookieepedia.

Comment: Welcome Tim. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when. Enjoy the site.